# updating taxonomy

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, taxonomy, managed-metadata-service

Users search for items based on taxonomy field. suppose you have a MMS Field with name "departement" which can get value (IT, economy, ...). after a while the client wants to change the name of its IT departement to "SUPPORT" departement, so we need to change the MMS data. and all new documents will get "SUPPORT" as value for departement field. Now the client wants that if you search for IT or SUPPPORT will get same result (all documents that have IT or Support for its deparement taxonomy field). is it possible? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the scenario correctly, you have TERM SET called *Department* that contains TERMS like *IT, Economy*.

In this case you could create new term inside the term set "*Department*", and name it "*SUPPORT*". Then you should merge the *IT* term to the new "*SUPPORT*" term.

**Note!** This will remove term *IT*, so you can no longer use *IT* when you create new documents. Instead it will make *IT* as a label for term "*SUPPORT*", meaning all new documents you can only tag with "*SUPPORT*", but all old existing documents will still retain *IT*. So if you would then search for "*SUPPORT*" department documents, you would get both new ones with "*SUPPORT*" and old ones with *IT* defined.

It might be good idea to test merging with some test terms and term sets so you can be sure this suggestion doesn't have any drawbacks in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much. just one single question. How do you merge the IT term to the new "SUPPORT" term? is it possible by powershell?

Comment: You can merge it using browser in Term Store Management: http://sharepointsoldiers.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/good2know-merge-termswhat-does-it-do/

Comment: I marked your answer as right answer, I found an article describes how you merge terms by using powershell. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The termset  value has changed from IT to Support.

You can search using the termset Guid and this will find both, but this is not very user friendly. However you can change your result set to do this.

http://sharepointpals.com/post/How-TaxonomyField-Managed-Property-renders-on-Search-Service-Application-in-SharePoint-2013

You could add a label with the previous value, and then use some jscript to find the current value

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5028e3a8-6d9a-4623-b345-5ef68af55837/get-taxonomy-label-based-on-term-guid-using-javascript?forum=sharepointdevelopment